# Toggle table rows with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

I have a normal html table.

Each `<tr>` has attributes `data-id` and `data-parent-id`.

I want to toggle underlying `<tr>` when I click on a `<tr>`.

I have made a short bad solution:

```
$("tr[data-id]").click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("data-id"); // get id from clicked tr

    $(this).siblings('tr[data-parent-id="' + id + '"]').each(function () { // iterate through all tr under clicked tr
        $(this).toggle(); // toggle first level under clicked tr
        var id = $(this).attr("data-id"); // get id from first level under clicked tr

        $(this).siblings('tr[data-parent-id="' + id + '"]').each(function () { // iterate through all tr under first level under clicked tr
            $(this).toggle(); // toggle _second level_ under clicked tr
            var id = $(this).attr("data-id"); // get id from _second_ level under clicked tr

            $(this).siblings('tr[data-parent-id="' + id + '"]').each(function () { // iterate through all tr under second level under clicked tr
                $(this).toggle(); // toggle _third_ level under clicked tr
            });
        });
    });
});
```

In my example I loop through each level but I don't know how to make a "never ending" traversing. I have specified only 3 levels of `<tr>` but it should be limitless.

It seems that http://ludo.cubicphuse.nl/jquery-treetable/ does what I want but I think it could be done much simpler and when I have a huge table I think it's better to hide the collapsed table rows with css instead of waiting for the javascript to do this (it flickers because of the loading).

How can I make a loop that checks for every `<tr>` if any other `<tr>` has its `data-id` as `data-parent-id`?

**Edit**:

Html

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-id="1" data-parent-id=""></tr>
    <tr data-id="2" data-parent-id="1"></tr>
    <tr data-id="3" data-parent-id="1"></tr>
    <tr data-id="4" data-parent-id="3"></tr>
    <tr data-id="5" data-parent-id="4"></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What do you mean by levels..? Do you have `<tr>` inside `<tr>`? If so, I don't think it's valid `HTML`. Please provide the sample `HTML` and `CSS` required to reproduce this..

Comment: just a daft question but if you are using data attributes, why not use `.data()` instead of `.attr()`?

Comment: I've updated with sample html :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need recursivity :

```
$("tr[data-id]").click(function () {
    Expand($(this).attr("data-id"));
}

function Expand(id)
{
     $('tr[data-parent-id="' + id + '"]').each(function () {
         $(this).toggle();
         Expand($(this).attr("data-id"));
     });
}
```

You got to be carefull with recursivity cause it may create and endless loop. In this case it will stop when it will reach a tr that as no data-parent-id (the root).